# Algorithm to replace all white spaces with %20 with python

Tags: python

Cracking the code chapter 1 has a question to replace all white spaces with `%20`, and there are multiple solutions available online that count string character and  go back to forward to replace them, but I am curious why not just use `replace` and replace all white space with `%20`?

```
string.replace(' ','%20')
```

Is there any specific behind it that I am missing in terms of space or time complexity?

Comment: The reason is "to learn more Python".

Comment: Imagine a world that does not have `.replace()` yet. You have been just asked to implement it.

Comment: is that the only reason, no other aspect from time or space complexity, i see people who have coded in java are using this whole big approach too

Comment: And beyond `str.replace`, the best way to do this is with `urllib.parse.quote()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `replace` method available in python is the best option you can use for such tasks in the majority of the cases. But the solutions you've seen on the Internet are to show or give a hint how such methods as `replace` work.